# polling using f:ajax:: Hi Have been using setInterval and f:ajax to poll below is the code kindly advise what is wrong here:

Tags: ajax, jsf

Have used setInterval to call ajax method which will render the value on page or probably keep updating the page. But in debug the control does not comes to ajax method in bean. please advise the issue in below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:body>

    <script>
    setInterval(function() { 
        document.getElementById("changeme").click();
        }, 3000);
    </script>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example</h3>

        <h:form>
           <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
             <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
           </h:commandButton>

           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>
           <h2><h:outputText id="countsee" value="#{helloBean.name}" /></h2>    

<h:commandButton id="changeme" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{helloBean.updates}" render="countsee" ></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>




import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private static int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSayWelcome(){
       //check if null?
       if("".equals(name) || name ==null){
        return "";
       }else{
        return "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
       }
    }
    public void getUpdates(ActionBehaviorEvent event){
           System.out.println("Printing"+count);
           this.name=name+"agdam";

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `helloBean` code where you are calling `updates` method.

Comment: Hi Dinal: public void getUpdates(ActionBehaviorEvent event){
           System.out.println("Printing"+count);
           this.name=name+"agdam";

    }

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the below:

```
public void updates(ActionBehaviorEvent event)
```

The method name and name given in the listener should be same.

Comment: Just identified document.getElementById("changeme") returns null and hence listener is not getting called, any suggestions

Comment: Hi All updated document.getElementById("form:changeme") and it worked